# Thread 1: Exception: "attempt to insert row 1 into section 1, but there are only 1 sections after the update"

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So I am trying to create a basic to do list app, but I keep getting this error and I have no idea what it truly means, and no idea how to fix it. Here is my code for the view controller:

```
class RemfoFightStyle: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var addTextField: UITextField!
   
    
    var fightStyle: [String] = ["Light to heavy punches",
    "Lots of mix ups"]

    
    
    @IBAction func addButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    insertNewStyleTitle()
    }
    
    func insertNewStyleTitle() {
        
        fightStyle.append(addTextField.text!)
        
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: fightStyle.count - 2, section: 1)
        
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
        
        addTextField.text = ""
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fightStyle.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let fightTitle = fightStyle[indexPath.row]
   
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewCell")! as! NewCell
        _ = fightTitle.count
        
        cell.bigLabel
        .text = fightStyle[indexPath.row]
        
       return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            fightStyle.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            
            tableView.beginUpdates()
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
            tableView.endUpdates()
           
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: It sounds like the issue isn't necessarily with the table view code, but with the actual data. (Your code you posted looks pretty good, and despite not posting how many sections you defined - there's a table view delegate for that - I'm assuming you only have one.) Any chance you could at least post some hard-coded data that will duplicate the issue? Even better, could you post more *complete* code that I could copy/paste that will duplicate your issue?

Answer (score 0):

`let indexPath = IndexPath(row: fightStyle.count - 2, section: 1)`

Rows and sections are zero-based. You only have one section so the second parameter should be `0`.